# How can I start a .jar file with a specific java.exe file, while still executing the .jar in its own directory, using batch?

Tags: java, batch-file, path

I need to start a .jar file with a specific java version, but if I path to the java version with:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin" 
java -jar C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\file\jarfile.jar
```

then the .jar file starts with java, but doesn't execute in its own directory, and instead executes in the java directory. I need it to execute in its own directory because it creates and needs the files in its own directory. How can I write this so that it starts with the java.exe that's in Program Files, but creates and reads files in the "file" folder, using batch?

Comment: `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin\java" -jar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have realized, if the path within the command didn't apply to the .jar, then I just needed to path to java.exe in the command. `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin\java.exe" -jar jarfile.jar` worked perfectly.